# Readable file with the right owner

Tags: php, linux, shell

A script which has to read a file with different owners

I have a php script which has to read a txt file. The script and the file are in different path on linux and have different owners.

The php script has apache:apache as owners, while the txt file has mis_admins:portalemis.

Unfortunately the txt file is generated automatically from another script (that I can't change it) and it's refreshing every 5 minutes. The rights on this file are only: -rw-------

The portion of the script which uses the file is the following function:

```
function readfilelinux($file,$azione)
{
    $buffer= '';
    $inizio='';
    $i = 1;
        $contarighe='0';
        $agent='';
        $arrFile= array();

    if( file_exists( $file ) && is_readable( $file ) )
    {
        $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );
        while (!feof ($fp) )
        {
                $tempstr = stream_get_line( $fp, 1024,"\n" );
                        $arrFile[$contarighe] = $tempstr;
                        $contarighe=$contarighe+1;
        }
        fclose($fp);
                return $arrFile;
    }
    else
    {
       return "FNT";
    }
}
```

But it returns always FNT because of the different owners.

I tried to change the txt file's owners to apache:apache and it works, but as said before it never updated anymore because the other script uses mis_admin:portalemis.

Is there a way to let the file readable, maybe including owner apache into group portalemis... or what else?

Comment: The file is not readable by group, only by owner. You need to run the script as the owner.

Comment: You don't want to run the php as `root`, so you need to change permissions somewhere,
I would try to set `umask`  to `022` and add `portalemis` as a secondary group for apache.
When that doesn't work, change something in the `mis_admin`: Call `chmod` right after the script is finished.

Comment: Is the data file deleted and regenerated, or overwritten? If the latter, you can just change its permissions to allow the script to read. You could also consider adding a default acl to the directory that adds appropriate access for the script to any files created there.